# How do I disconnect from SignalR when the user logs out?

Tags: signalr, aspnetboilerplate

when a user logs off my application (setting `enc_token` to `null`) how do I disable signalR (using angular)?

I tried
        `abp.signalr = null;`

The issue is, if a user logs off then back on again, 2 connections are then made. What is the correct way to stop it?

Comment: what version of APB are you using?

Comment: It seems the websocket connection is already closed when you log out. What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Like I said, when I log out and log back in, it gets 2 events. If i log out and back in again, it will fire 3 events.

Comment: 1. You didn't say that. 2. Fire what events?

Comment: Not yet no. I'll look at it again soon.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR version 2 does not have a built-in server API for disconnecting clients. Here's the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#how-to-disconnect-a-client-in-server-code) stating it.

Essentially, you are dealing with a situation where the handling of connections, reconnects, etc. are not aligning.

You could assign your logged in user to a group and just send data based on group. This way it won't matter if you have multiple connections. When they are disconnected, remove them from the group using OnDisconnect(). Check out the section on Working with Groups at the same link.